# Region-based memory management for recursive type

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, types-and-programming-languages

In the chapter 4 of Pierce's TAPL which discusses the implementation of untyped arithmetic expressions, the author said

> The most important [for the implementation requirements] are automatic storage management... and... pattern matching over structured data types.

Indeed, which the recursive type is natural in ML, it is [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust) in Rust, e.g.

```rust
type Info = String;

enum Term {
    ...
    TmIf(Info, Term, Term, Term),
    ...
}
```

instead `Term` should be boxed as

```rust
enum Term {
    ...
    TmIf(Info, Box<Term>, Box<Term>, Box<Term>),
    ...
}
```

Similarly, in C/C++, we must use pointers for members in such a recursive type.

While Rust is region-based (and C/C++ is manual) memory management, I wonder whether or not automatic (garbage collection) memory management is obligatory for a language which is capable to represent naturally recursive types?

Comment: [MLKit](http://www.mlton.org/MLKit) uses regions. I think you'd be interested in reading its documentation or the papers about it.